# R : misunderstanding with NA and vector's building

Tags: r, vector, na

I have two vectors : vector1 and vector2 with same length. I would like to get only the value of vector1 where vector1 is not na, and where vector2 is not na. I tried with that code, but it doesn't work :

```
vector1step1<-ifelse(((is.na(vector1)==F)&(is.na(vector2)==F)), vector1, NA)
vector1step2<-vector1step1[!is.na(vector1step1)]
```

An idea ?
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Try `vector1[!is.na(vector1) & !is.na(vector2)]`

Comment: @docendodiscimus you should go ahead and post that as the answer.

Answer (score -2):

The best way of thinking about this is probably as a data.frame or matrix, and creating a third vector that results from an apply call to each row. Something like

```
dta <- data.frame(v1 = vector_step1, v2=vector_step2)
dta$v3 <- apply(dta, 1, function(x) ifelse(!is.na(x[1]), x[1], x[2]))
```

The `1` in apply means rowwise, slicing out one row at a time. The first element in each slice, temporarily renamed x[1], will be from v1, the second, temporarily renamed x[2] will be from the same row, but v2.

You could also extend the code in apply to deal with cases where both v1 and v2 are `NA`, by nesting in another `ifelse` statement.

Comment: No, `apply` is not the best way here. There is no reason to loop over the rows. Also, don't use `ifelse` for length-1 vectors. Use `if` and `else` in such a case.